# How can I use the /execute command to make particles

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I saw a YouTube video of the YouTuber Timplayz watching a tiktok for making particles in minecraft so I watched the video but then I forgot what command it was and I couldn't find the video on YouTube. I want to know what that `/execute` command was?

Comment: Hi @BronsonHunter, pppery was just trying to help improve your question a bit, so I've gone ahead and put their edit back. For more info on edits, check out [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: but it does include redstone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best Way is

```
/particle [the particle effect you want] X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 7 3 7 1 200
```

Example

```
/particle minecraft:portal -52 67 207 7 3 7 1 200
```

Comment: This didn’t completely answer the question. You should probably add what the execute could’ve been for, it was likely to spawn them in the player’s location using tildes `~`

Comment: I have just told him, that it is better to use **/particle** command.

Comment: True, but it would be more complete, as this was part of OP's question: "I want to know what that /execute command was?"

Comment: @Kladeon I more meant that he would want to use `/execute` and `/particle` (you cannot make particles without `/particle`!) together, as the full question asked, although it looks like the owner has accepted it now.